# Python multithreading wrong data mapped

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, list

I was making an Email filter to filter out non-work domains and for some reason, it's mapping the domains as well as the email list.
expected behaviour would be for each thread to take an email and try to match it against all domains and if it doesn't match any of them it returns it to the main function to append it to the filtered file
current behaviour it maps the domains list so for the first email it checks only the first domain, the second domain for the second and so on

````
domains = open("domains_test.txt", 'r')


def filter_list(unfiltered_email):
    to_filter = 0
    for domain in domains:
        print("checking " + domain + " for " + unfiltered_email)
        matcher = unfiltered_email.lower().find(domain.lower())
        if matcher != -1:
            to_filter = 1
    if to_filter == 0:
        print(to_filter)
        return(unfiltered_email)


with open("test.txt", "r") as websites, open("filtered.txt", "a") as filtered:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:

        for filtered_email in executor.map(filter_list, websites):
            filtered.write(filtered_email)```







from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

domains = open("domains_test.txt", 'r')
emails = open("test.txt", "r")
filtered = open("filtered.txt", "a")
def filter_list(unfiltered_email):

    to_filter = 0
    for domain in domains:
        print("checking " + domain + " for " + unfiltered_email)
        matcher = unfiltered_email.lower().find(domain.lower())
        if matcher != -1:
            to_filter = 1
    if to_filter == 0:
        filtered.write(unfiltered_email)


for email in emails:
    filter_list(email)
````

edit: I removed multithreading yet the issue persists

```
domains = open("domains_test.txt", 'r')
emails = open("test.txt", "r")
filtered = open("filtered.txt", "a")
def filter_list(unfiltered_email):

    to_filter = 0
    for domain in domains:
        print("checking " + domain + " for " + unfiltered_email)
        matcher = unfiltered_email.lower().find(domain.lower())
        if matcher != -1:
            to_filter = 1
    if to_filter == 0:
        filtered.write(unfiltered_email)


for email in emails:
    filter_list(email)
```

Comment: You need to open and close domains_test.txt within the thread. The problem is that the file input stream is exhausted after the first thread completes. In fact, theoretically, different threads could end up consuming different parts of the file. Also, bear in mind that filter_list could implicitly return None

Comment: but why would I open it within the thread and multiple times ultimately if it doesn't change at all during the execution of the code?

Comment: Why are you using multithreading for this? Just seems to complicate things for no advantage.

Comment: I am trying to filter all current users emails which is a large list, I can do it normally but it would take hours if not days

Comment: And you think multithreading is going to make it faster?

Comment: It should? why wouldn't it?

Comment: Because it doesn't do such things in parallel, so all you're doing is adding overhead, likely making it *slower*.

Comment: Multithreading in Python is only a win for I/O-bound functions that spend most of their time waiting for I/O of some kind.  The global interpreter lock means that only one thread at a time can be executing Python code, so CPU-bound functions do not benefit from multithreading.

Comment: Your second example has the same problem.  After you run `filter_list` once, the file `domains` is positioned at the end.  All future reads will fail.  You should read that file into a list and process the list several times.